# Using Selenium web driver in C#, FirefoxWebDriver Navagate().GoTo(URL) fails

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

So I'm doing website test automation and we are adding Firefox to the browsers we support. The code in question that we are using is.

```
 switch (m_WebPageSettings.Browser)
     {
         case WebBrowserType.InternerExplorer:
             m_Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                 break;
         case WebBrowserType.FireFox:
             m_Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                 break;
     }   
 m_Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(m_WebPageUrl);
```

Basically when the driver is instantilized, it will open an instance of Firefox, but the NavigateTo doesn't actually work.

Comment: What version of Selenium and Firefox are you running?  Is there an exception thrown on GoToUrl?

Comment: Using Firefox 23.0.1 and Selenium 2.35, Karl's answer was the correct solution though. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out that after many hours of chasing solution, that it was simply that the FirefoxDriver requires Http:// at the beginning of the URL.